# Finding the area of crosssections

Tags: geometry

[image]

Let the radious of the circle is r. Now if i want to find out the area of the crosssection **( mentioned by red color)** then how to proceed?

Comment: I have editted. Check please

Answer (score 2):

1. Calculate the area of the circe with center O.
2. Calculate the area of the section PMN, when M and N are the intersections between the two circles. This can be done by firstly calculation the angle MPO.
3. substruct the results.

**EDIT:**

The calculation of angle MPO is done by observing triangle POM is a equilateral triangle.